# How do we handle questions where the OP wants to do something destructive to their OS?

Tags: discussion, questions

How should we handle questions like

[How to delete "Program Files (x86)" folder after windows login](https://superuser.com/q/628266/101850)

where the asker wants to do something that is unambiguously destructive to the OS/computer and it is clear that they have no idea what they’re doing?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, looking at the question, the comments and answers cover the situation perfectly well.

1. The comments repeatedly say why this is a bad idea.
2. The answers cover things you need to do this relatively safely.
3. The OP has a definite goal, though, its an XY question.

I think it was handled pretty well.

I'd add this wasn't quite what I expected when I saw the question title in the feeds. If someone was *actually* suicidal, rather than at risk of destroying their install, the process would be very different.

Comment: Well, “obviously suicidal” is something different than “suicidal”.